# Stuck with simple webscraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the coin names from the following website. 
https://www.block123.com/en/nav/065285354703.htm 
I have trawled stack overflow but can't understand why I am not getting the 
full list of names from the website. I am new to this so appreciate everyones 
help and patience

```
    url = 'https://www.block123.com/en/nav/065285354703.htm'

    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


    for coin in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'portfolio-content item-content'}):
      print(coin.find("div", attrs={"class":"name"}))
```

I have now written a **scraper** in selenium to enable me to input password info. 
I can then access the full portfolio details and I have **scraped** all the coins but also get lots of unwanted text with the same class name.
The code suggested in the answer provided was really helpful to remove these by only including elements that had 'Portfolio'  in the previous  
I am unsure how to apply this when using selenium any help would be much appreciated

```
    driver.get(links['https://www.block123.com/en/nav/065285354703.htm'])
    coins = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("portfolio-item")
    coin_names = [coin.find_element_by_class_name('name').text for coin in coins]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if previous `<div>` for each `div`s with `'class':'portfolio-content item-content'` contains text `Portfolio` to identify if the div contains coins or not, if yes, extract coin names

```
for item in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'portfolio-content item-content'}):
    if 'Portfolio' in item.find_previous('div').text:
        coins = [coin.text for coin in item.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"name"})]
        print(coins)
```

```
['YEECO', 'SoundArio', 'COVA']
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it. This still only gives 3 coins from the 29 listed in portfolio content. I've tried to use access the names from the attribute tag but very new to this and feel like i'm getting no where with it 

Comment: i can only see three when i open the link, rest needs logging in.

Comment: ha. .. I think here lies the problem. Ill go and do some research and try to figure out how to deal with the password issue. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi I have edited my question, after using selenium instead of BS, if you could help me apply the really useful code you provided in the previous answer i would be very grateful